# What's the correct stock ROM for my unlocked Moto E5 Play?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, stock-rom

So I was working on backing up my phone after installing TWRP so that I could restore it if it had an issue, but it had an issue. It thinks its decrypted and I can't get it to boot, wiping does seemingly nothing.

My next step to troubleshoot is to reflash a stock ROM, but here's the thing: I bought my phone unlocked with no carrier.

```
$ fastboot getvar product
product: james
```

According to the fastboot menu, I have the XT1921-2, which according to Motorola's documentation, is the Cricket Wireless variant, which seems to have ROMs here: https://mirrors.lolinet.com/firmware/moto/james/official/Cricket/

I don't want the Cricket Wireless ROM, and my device is not subsidized (as indicated by the filenames), it's wholly owned and hasn't ever really been used to connect to a network. Which ROM am I supposed to use to restore my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. Besides the carrier-specific ROMs, Motorola has a "retail channel", called RETUS (Retail - US, I believe).

This is not tied to any carrier, and you can match the factory version by comparing with what you get here:

```
# fastboot getvar ro.build.fingerprint
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[0]: motorola/james/james:8.0.0/OPP27.9
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[1]: 1-121/42:user/release-keys
```

Combine the two lines, and we have

```
motorola/james/james:8.0.0/OPP27.91-121/42:user/release-keys
```